# Given a list of token accounts for a wallet, how do I determine which accounts the user/wallet has mintAuthority?

Tags: spl-token, token, mint, authority

I built a ui using NextJS and the Solana wallet adapter library. I'm using `getParsedTokenAccountsByowner` to display all token accounts when the user connects their wallet. I want to map over all these token accounts and add a key value pair of isMintAuthority to them so I can display a "Mint Tokens" button to the user, IF they have mintAuthority. Here's the react-query hook I put together:

```
export function useGetMintAuthority({ mintAddress }: { mintAddress: PublicKey }) {
  const { connection } = useConnection();

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ["get-mint-authority", { endpoint: connection.rpcEndpoint, mintAddress }],
    queryFn: async () => {
      // Fetch the account info for the mint address
      const accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(mintAddress);
      if (!accountInfo) throw new Error("Failed to find mint account");

      // Parse the account info to get the mint data
      const mintData = MintLayout.decode(accountInfo.data);

      // The mint authority is an optional field, so it could be null
      const mintAuthority = mintData.mintAuthority ? new PublicKey(mintData.mintAuthority) : null;

      return mintAuthority;
    },
  });
}
```

The problem is this only works for one account at a time. Without getting into the limitations and headache of React Hooks inside loops or conditionals and the asynchronous nature of fetching mint authority. Is there a best way or recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch multiple accounts together, using the [`getMultipleAccounts` RPC call](https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/getmultipleaccounts). That's also available in web3.js as [`connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMultipleAccountsInfo) and [`connection.getMultipleParsedAccounts`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getMultipleParsedAccounts). In any case that request will fetch up to 100 accounts at a time.

Then your hook would take a set of mint addresses as input, and perhaps return a map of address -> mint authority.

Depending on your usage pattern you might still want to cache per mint and just fetch the missing ones, instead of caching by list.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what worked for me. I abandoned trying to do this within a hook and instead opted for an `async function`. Since I already have all the token accounts of the owner, which I am getting back from `getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner` I just wanted to add this `isMintAuthority: boolean` key pair to that object before I do some bit of rendering logic. This way I can easily check this key pair and display a mint button if it's true. Obviously TS will make you write twice the amount of code, but whatevs.

```
type EnhancedAccount = {
  pubkey: PublicKey;
  account: AccountInfo<ParsedAccountData>;
  isMintAuthority: boolean;
};

type TokenAccount = {
  pubkey: PublicKey;
  account: AccountInfo<ParsedAccountData>;
};

async function enhanceAccountsWithMintAuthority(
  accounts: TokenAccount[],
  connection: Connection,
  userAddress: PublicKey
): Promise<EnhancedAccount[]> {
  const enhancedAccounts = await Promise.all(
    accounts.map(async (account) => {
      const mintAddress = new PublicKey(account.account.data.parsed.info.mint);
      const mintAccountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(mintAddress);
      if (!mintAccountInfo) throw new Error("Failed to find mint account");

      const mintData = MintLayout.decode(mintAccountInfo.data);
      const isMintAuthority = mintData.mintAuthority && new PublicKey(mintData.mintAuthority).equals(userAddress);

      // Ensure the returned object matches the EnhancedAccount type
      return {
        pubkey: account.pubkey,
        account: account.account,
        isMintAuthority,
      };
    })
  );

  return enhancedAccounts;
}
```